# Blocking MAC Address does not work on DHCPv6 request

Tags: dhcp, iptables

I blocked a MAC address of a client on my DHCP Server running on Ubuntu 12.10 using

> iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source  -j DROP

But I am still getting DHCP requests from the client and the client is getting the IP address from my DHCP server too. I think the command does not work for broadcast messages. Is there any other technique to do it? I do not have access to the DHCP Server code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iptables` is the IPv4 implementation of iptables.  For the IPv6 version, you need to use `ip6tables`

Using the same command, but with `ip6tables` should make that work.

Remember to back up your rules, though, for both iptables and ip6tables, with `iptables-save > /some/path` and `ip6tables-save > /some/path`, or use `iptables-persistent` and then save the rules, so that you can recall the rules if the system restarts or something!